# Directory and file scanner with java.nio.file*;

Tags: java, path, nio

How to achieve the same functionality in java.io.File;

```
List<File> List = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(directory, 
                                    TrueFileFilter.TRUE, TrueFileFilter.TRUE);
String fileID = f.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll(staticRoot, "");
```

while refactoring to java.nio.file.*;

```
DirectoryStream<Path> List = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(directory));    
String fileID = f.???
```

What method would return same output as in java.io.File Package?
Thanks.

I have tried

```
String fileID = f.toAbsolutePath().toString().replaceAll(staticRoot, "");

for (Path f : fList) {
    String fileID = f.toAbsolutePath().toString().replaceAll(staticRoot, "");
    System.out.println("file ID : " + fileID);
    String parentID = null;
}
```

staticRoot = /home/test/dir1/dir10/test9.txt
the result should cut '/home/test/' and return only dir1/dir10/test9.txt

Answer (score 2):

Since `FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(directory, TrueFileFilter.TRUE, TrueFileFilter.TRUE)` will recursively visit all sub directories in `directory` you most likely want to replace it with [`Files.walk(Path, FileVisitOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...)) method.

> Return a Stream that is lazily populated with Path by walking the file tree rooted at a given starting file. The file tree is traversed depth-first, the elements in the stream are Path objects that are obtained as if by resolving the relative path against start.

Answer (score 0):

Given a j.n.f.Path object representing `/home/test/dir1/dir10/test9.txt`, call `.getParent()` for something representing dir10. Then, if you have a path that represents `/home/test/dir1/dir10/subdir1/subdir2/foo.txt` and you want to turn that into `subdir1/subdir2/foo.txt`, you can use the `relativize` method of j.f.Path to do so. No need for replace nor replaceAll.

NB: You're using replaceAll wrong. replaceAll takes a regular expression as first argument, and a replacement as second, and replaces all hits on that regular expression. The replace method takes a string as argument, the replacement as second argument, and.. also replaces all. Given that your staticRoot is not a regexp, you're using the wrong call. Just a lesson for next time. Yes, the names are confusing.